# Why C++20 doesn't support out-of-order designated initializer?

Tags: c++, c++20, designated-initializer

While I was reading [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers), I had a question about this paragraph:

> Note: out-of-order designated initialization, nested designated
>   initialization, mixing of designated initializers and regular
>   initializers, and designated initialization of arrays are all
>   supported in the C programming language, but are not allowed in C++.

Is there any technical reason that prevents C++ from supporting out-of-order designated initialization?

Comment: Probably because the things mentioned have always been a bit of a safety hazard in C.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, the rationale is covered in *Annex C (informative)
Compatibility* specifically [[diff.dcl]p10](http://eel.is/c++draft/diff.dcl#10) (*emphasis mine*):

> Affected subclause: [dcl.init.aggr] Change: In C++, designated
>   initialization support is restricted compared to the corresponding
>   functionality in C. In C++, designators for non-static data members
>   **must be specified in declaration order**, designators for array elements
>   and nested designators are not supported, and designated and
>   non-designated initializers cannot be mixed in the same initializer
>   list. Example:
>
> ```
> struct A { int x, y; };
> struct B { struct A a; };
> struct A a = {.y = 1, .x = 2};  // valid C, invalid C++
> int arr[3] = {[1] = 5};         // valid C, invalid C++
> struct B b = {.a.x = 0};        // valid C, invalid C++
> struct A c = {.x = 1, 2};       // valid C, invalid C++
> ```
>
> Rationale: **In C++, members are destroyed in reverse construction order and the elements of an initializer list are evaluated in lexical order, so field initializers must be specified in order.**
>   Array designators conflict with lambda-expression syntax.
>   Nested designators are seldom used.

The [first revision of the proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0329r0.pdf) also discusses this topic:

> To meet these expectations for guaranteed copy elision, we require the designators to appear
>   as a subsequence of the data member declaration sequence, so that the evaluation order
>   matches the declaration order, and it is also textually left­to­right in designated initialization

You can obtain the last revision [here](https://wg21.link/p0329).

Comment: I also did a [twitter poll on this recently](https://twitter.com/shafikyaghmour/status/1007671525313413122)

Comment: I do not see a problem if it would be specified as: order of initialization will be the same as members order. It happened with init list already before. Are there any negative consequences if this is allowed?

Comment: @GermánDiago, I guess they consider it (allowing arbitrary order in member init list) a bad design decision, and don't want to spread it further: after all, hopefully most programmers never violate that order anyway, thanks to `-Wall`.

Comment: They should just allow most/all + require warnings. Esp. in the shadow of much bigger problems that have been embraced (like the impossibly cumbersome init. rules, incl. legitimizing uninitialized data _in some cases, but not others_, and even euphemizing it as "default-initialized" -- hilarious...:) )

Answer (score 9):

Having only a small fraction of designated initialization options from C is painful. Perhaps it will be rectified in the future. For now, some compilers are a bit less strict than C++20 standard. This snippet:

```
struct A {int x, y;};
A a = {.y=2, .x=4};
```

compiles with a warning and runs fine with `clang-10.0.0` and newer (see https://godbolt.org/z/Ybnzz5chx).